# Pytrends: The request failed: Google returned a response with code 429

Tags: python, google-trends

I'm using Pytrends to extract Google trends data, like:

```
from pytrends.request import TrendReq
pytrend = TrendReq()
pytrend.build_payload(kw_list=['bitcoin'], cat=0, timeframe=from_date+' '+today_date)
```

And it returns an error:

```
ResponseError: The request failed: Google returned a response with code 429.
```

I made it yesterday and for some reason it doesn't work now! The source code from github failed too:

```
pytrends = TrendReq(hl='en-US', tz=360, proxies = {'https': 'https://34.203.233.13:80'})
```

How can I fix this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Google will block your ip pretty fast if they suspect you spamming or scraping or any other kind of abuse of the system

Comment: @zimdero Thanks, what can I do if I still wanna use it? The "proxies" command doesn't work.

Comment: I am actively trying to solve this same exact problem. Im doing research for an Academic paper and it was working yesterday and today I havent been able to get one successful response. Looking forward to finding a good solution...

Comment: @WWH98932 What are you working on? I am making the same exact search. Im thinking we're going to have to download the csv file from the web interface and then bring it in to JupyterLab and into a DataFrame. That's the approach I am leaning towards anyway.

Comment: @lopezdp Same, I'm doing it manually, it's really annoying. I'll go somewhere else tomorrow to see if it can change my IP address...

Comment: To me, it seems like it has blocked any call from the script

Comment: Maybe using time.sleep() you can get results.

Comment: anyone found a solution to this?
when I run my code on my computer it goes ok, but when I do that on my prod environment (on AWS) I'm getting this 429

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This one took a while but it turned out the library just needed an update. You can check out a few of the approaches I posted here, both of which resulted in Status 429 Responses:

https://github.com/GeneralMills/pytrends/issues/243

Ultimately, I was able to get it working again by running the following command from my bash prompt:

Run:

`pip install --upgrade --user git+https://github.com/GeneralMills/pytrends`

For the latest version.

Hope that works for you too.

EDIT:

If you can't upgrade from source you may have some luck with:

`pip install pytrends --upgrade`

Also, make sure you're running git as an administrator if on Windows.

Comment: @WWH98932 did you try restarting the kernal?

Comment: It returned the following error when I tried to upgrade it using your command:

Comment: Cannot find command 'git' - do you have 'git' installed and in your PATH?

Comment: umm yes. This works for me. It sounds like you do not have git installed or your PATH variable is not set to accept the git command. You should have git + python3 installed at least that's my environment. I upgraded directly from their source.

Comment: @WWH98932 see the EDIT I added to the answer and see if that helps

Comment: @WWH98932 are you experiencing this error again by any chance? im getting it again, Google mustve changed their algo agin or something to prevent our research from happening... any news?

Comment: pip3.6 install --upgrade --user git+https://github.com/GeneralMills/pytrends forced update from 4.4 to 4.5 Thank you!

Comment: @qpaycm lol! the struggle is real! I remember that particular problem being quite troublesome for me too back then... Here is the project that I used that library on in case it can help to give you any insight: https://github.com/lopezdp/MachineLearningResearch/blob/master/CryptoCurrencyResearch/PricingResearch.ipynb

Comment: Thanks to you finished my research in few hours. Today 2nd run had to proxy after experiencing 429. Now I think with a proxy carousel there will be a higher chance of getting a Max retries exceeded error. Guess I should handle it from > exceptions.py ?

Comment: @qpaycm It depends on what you are doing. I did experience the same as well after correcting the issues as stated. What I had to do was play around with the qty of requests I was making per iteration of my loop. In my specific case I was querying 60 day periods and I just switched it to 90 periods to minimize the total number of iteration cycles to stay under the 429 limit. I suspect you may have something similar where you can just just tweak the size of the request volume in order to reduce the total request iterations a bit... thats what I did anyway.

Comment: @lopezdp I was getting: Max retries exceeded error. Fixed editing request.py. 2 lines after `import requests`(line 8) add `from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter` 
`from requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry import Retry` and 2 lines after `s=requests.session()` (line 77) add `retry = Retry(connect=3, backoff_factor=0.5)`
 `adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry)`

Comment: @lopezdp all thx to you my man! Forked it to add 2 parameters: retries and backoff_factor. Few ideas: to split process to threads with queue and add proxy carousel class with it's own thread and queue for never-ending analysis, but I don't know if I am actually going to do that :-p

Answer (score 13):

TLDR; I solved the problem with a custom patch

## Explanation

The problem comes from the Google bot recognition system. As other similar systems do, it stops serving too frequent requests coming from suspicious clients. Some of the features used to recognize trustworthy clients are the presence of specific headers generated by the javascript code present on the web pages. Unfortunately, the python requests library does not provide such a level of camouflage against those bot recognition systems since javascript code is not even executed.
So the idea behind my patch is to leverage the headers generated by my browser interacting with google trends. Those headers are generated by the browser meanwhile I am logged in using my Google account, in other words, those headers are linked with my google account, so for them, I am trustworthy.

## Solution

I solved in the following way:

1. First of all you must use google trends from your web browser while you are logged in with your Google Account;
2. In order to track the actual HTTP GET made: (I am using Chromium) Go into "More Tools" -> "Developers Tools" -> "Network" tab.
3. Visit the [Google Trend](https://trends.google.com/trends/) page and perform a search for a trend; it will trigger a lot of HTTP requests on the left sidebar of the "Network" tab;
4. Identify the GET request (in my case it was /trends/explore?q=topic&geo=US) and right-click on it and select Copy -> Copy as cURL;
5. Then go to [this page](https://curl.trillworks.com/) and paste the cURL script on the left side and copy the "headers" dictionary you can find inside the python script generated on the right side of the page;
6. Then go to your code and subclass the TrendReq class, so you can pass the custom header just copied:

```py
from pytrends.request import TrendReq as UTrendReq
GET_METHOD='get'

import requests

headers = {
...
}


class TrendReq(UTrendReq):
    def _get_data(self, url, method=GET_METHOD, trim_chars=0, **kwargs):
        return super()._get_data(url, method=GET_METHOD, trim_chars=trim_chars, headers=headers, **kwargs)
```

7. Remove any "import TrendReq" from your code since now it will use this you just created;
8. Retry again;
9. If in any future the error message comes back: repeat the procedure. You need to update the header dictionary with fresh values and it may trigger the captcha mechanism.

Comment: Is it possible to use the requests_args argument at TrendReq to add the headers? Or do you need to edit the source?

Comment: As far as I remember, is not possible to pass the header as argument of TrendReq's constructor. So, I applied this custom patch by overriding the _get_data method. Yes, I would need to edit the source, having the header passed in the init or directly during the actual call.

Comment: Looks like Google is blocking by IP. Because I did this headers change, but the blocking (HTTPS error 429) remained.

Comment: PyTrends now has an option to define headers. https://github.com/GeneralMills/pytrends/pull/553

Comment: The above link to "this page" (https://curl.trillworks.com/) appears to be broken, but https://curlconverter.com/ worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem even after updating the module with `pip install --upgrade --user git+https://github.com/GeneralMills/pytrends` and restart python.

But, the issue was solved via the below method:

Instead of

```
pytrends = TrendReq(hl='en-US', tz=360, timeout=(10,25), proxies=['https://34.203.233.13:80',], retries=2, backoff_factor=0.1, requests_args={'verify':False})
```

Just ran:

```
pytrend = TrendReq()
```

Hope this can be helpful!

Answer (score 1):

After running the upgrade command via pip install, you should restart the python kernel and reload the pytrend library.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and did something really similar to Antonio Ercole De Luca. For me, however, the issue was with the *cookies* and not the headers.

I created a subclass like Antonio did, but this time modifying the cookie method:

```
cookies = {
    "SEARCH_SAMESITE": "####",
    "SID": "####",
    .
    .
    .
}

class CookieTrendReq(TrendReq):
    def GetGoogleCookie(self):
        return dict(filter(lambda i: i[0] == 'NID', cookies.items()))
```

And I used the same method to get the cookies as he did to get the headers:

1. visit [trends.google.com](https://trends.google.com)
2. open developer tools and go to the network tab
3. make a search, and then right-click on the top GET request (should look like **explore?q=...**)
4. copy the request as bash-cURL
5. paste this into [curlconverter.com](https://curlconverter.com) and get the cookies!

Comment: You're a legend, this is the only thing that worked for me

Comment: For those using this approach: if it stops working after a few tries, attempt this: https://github.com/GeneralMills/pytrends/pull/553#issuecomment-1473742736 (make sure to uncomment the 'cookie' parameter in your headers dictionary when passing it in as a variable to requests_args of TrendReq.

Answer (score 0):

**Now we are facing same issue again following code will help to resolve 429 issue**

**For Interest below code will work with multiple retries by changing browsers**

```html
import json
import urllib.parse
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from curl_cffi import requests
import time

def build_payload(keywords, timeframe='now 7-d', geo='US'):
    token_payload = {
        'hl': 'en-US',
        'tz': '0',
        'req': {
            'comparisonItem': [{'keyword': keyword, 'time': timeframe, 'geo': geo} for keyword in keywords],
            'category': 0,
            'property': ''
        }
    }
    token_payload['req'] = json.dumps(token_payload['req'])
    return token_payload

def convert_to_desired_format(raw_data):
    trend_data = {}
    for entry in raw_data['default']['timelineData']:
        timestamp = int(entry['time'])
        date_time_str = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(timestamp).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        value = entry['value'][0]
        trend_data[date_time_str] = value
    return trend_data

# Cookies
def get_google_cookies(impersonate_version='chrome110'):
    with requests.Session() as session:
        session.get("https://www.google.com", impersonate=impersonate_version)
        return session.cookies

def fetch_trends_data(keywords, days_ago=7, geo='US', hl='en-US', max_retries=5, browser_version='chrome110', browser_switch_retries=2):
    browser_versions = ['chrome110', 'edge101', 'chrome107', 'chrome104', 'chrome100', 'chrome101', 'chrome99']
    current_browser_version_index = browser_versions.index(browser_version)
    cookies = get_google_cookies(impersonate_version=browser_versions[current_browser_version_index])

    for browser_retry in range(browser_switch_retries + 1):
        data_fetched = False  # Reset data_fetched to False at the beginning of each browser_retry
        with requests.Session() as s:
            # phase 1: token
            for retry in range(max_retries):
                time.sleep(2)
                token_payload = build_payload(keywords)
                url = 'https://trends.google.com/trends/api/explore'
                params = urllib.parse.urlencode(token_payload)
                full_url = f"{url}?{params}"
                response = s.get(full_url, impersonate=browser_versions[current_browser_version_index], cookies=cookies)
                if response.status_code == 200:
                    content = response.text[4:]
                    try:
                        data = json.loads(content)
                        widgets = data['widgets']
                        tokens = {}
                        request = {}
                        for widget in widgets:
                            if widget['id'] == 'TIMESERIES':
                                tokens['timeseries'] = widget['token']
                                request['timeseries'] = widget['request']
                        break  # Break out of the retry loop as we got the token
                    except json.JSONDecodeError:
                        print(f"Failed to decode JSON while fetching token, retrying {retry + 1}/{max_retries}")
                else:
                    print(f"Error {response.status_code} while fetching token, retrying {retry + 1}/{max_retries}")
            else:
                print(f"Exceeded maximum retry attempts ({max_retries}) while fetching token. Exiting...")
                return None

            # phase 2: trends data
            for retry in range(max_retries):
                time.sleep(5)
                req_string = json.dumps(request['timeseries'], separators=(',', ':'))
                encoded_req = urllib.parse.quote(req_string, safe=':,+')
                url = f"https://trends.google.com/trends/api/widgetdata/multiline?hl={hl}&tz=0&req={encoded_req}&token={tokens['timeseries']}&tz=0"
                response = s.get(url, impersonate=browser_versions[current_browser_version_index], cookies=cookies)
                if response.status_code == 200:
                    content = response.text[5:]
                    try:
                        raw_data = json.loads(content)
                        # Convert raw data
                        trend_data = convert_to_desired_format(raw_data)
                        data_fetched = True  # Set data_fetched to True as we have successfully fetched the trend data
                        return trend_data
                    except json.JSONDecodeError:
                        print(f"Failed to decode JSON while fetching trends data, retrying {retry + 1}/{max_retries}")
                else:
                    print(f"Error {response.status_code} while fetching trends data, retrying {retry + 1}/{max_retries}")
            else:
                print(f"Exceeded maximum retry attempts ({max_retries}) while fetching trends data.")

        # change browser
        if not data_fetched and browser_retry < browser_switch_retries:
            time.sleep(5)
            current_browser_version_index = (current_browser_version_index + 1) % len(browser_versions)
            print(f"Switching browser version to {browser_versions[current_browser_version_index]} and retrying...")

    print(f"Exceeded maximum browser switch attempts ({browser_switch_retries}). Exiting...")
    return None

# Example
keywords = ["test"]
trends_data = fetch_trends_data(keywords)
print(trends_data)
```

**Following code for Top and Rising Queries**

```html
import json
import urllib.parse
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from curl_cffi import requests
import time
import os


def build_payload(keywords, timeframe='now 1-H', geo=''):
    token_payload = {
        'hl': 'en-US',
        'tz': '0',
        'req': {
            'comparisonItem': [{'keyword': keyword, 'time': timeframe, 'geo': geo} for keyword in keywords],
            'category': 0,
            'property': ''
        }
    }
    token_payload['req'] = json.dumps(token_payload['req'])
    return token_payload

def convert_to_desired_format(raw_data):
    trend_data = {'TOP': {}, 'RISING': {}}

    if 'rankedList' in raw_data.get('default', {}):
        for item in raw_data['default']['rankedList']:
            for entry in item.get('rankedKeyword', []):
                query = entry.get('query')
                value = entry.get('value')
                if query and value:
                    link = entry.get('link', '')
                    trend_type = link.split('=')[-1].split('&')[0].upper() if link else None

                    if trend_type in ['TOP', 'RISING']:
                        trend_data[trend_type][query] = value
    return trend_data

def get_google_cookies(impersonate_version='chrome110'):
    with requests.Session() as session:
        session.get("https://www.google.com", impersonate=impersonate_version)
        return session.cookies

def fetch_trends_data(keywords, days_ago=7, geo='US', hl='en-US', max_retries=5, browser_version='chrome110', browser_switch_retries=2):
    browser_versions = ['chrome110', 'edge101', 'chrome107', 'chrome104', 'chrome100', 'chrome101', 'chrome99']
    current_browser_version_index = browser_versions.index(browser_version)
    cookies = get_google_cookies(impersonate_version=browser_versions[current_browser_version_index])

    for browser_retry in range(browser_switch_retries + 1):
        data_fetched = False
        with requests.Session() as s:
            # phase 1: token
            for retry in range(max_retries):
                time.sleep(2)
                token_payload = build_payload(keywords)
                url = 'https://trends.google.com/trends/api/explore'
                params = urllib.parse.urlencode(token_payload)
                full_url = f"{url}?{params}"
                response = s.get(full_url, impersonate=browser_versions[current_browser_version_index], cookies=cookies)
                if response.status_code == 200:
                    content = response.text[4:]
                    try:
                        data = json.loads(content)
                        widgets = data['widgets']
                        tokens = {}
                        request = {}
                        for widget in widgets:
                            if widget['id'] == 'RELATED_QUERIES':
                                tokens['related_queries'] = widget['token']
                                request['related_queries'] = widget['request']
                        break
                    except json.JSONDecodeError:
                        print(f"Failed to decode JSON while fetching token, retrying {retry + 1}/{max_retries}")
                else:
                    print(f"Error {response.status_code} while fetching token, retrying {retry + 1}/{max_retries}")
            else:
                print(f"Exceeded maximum retry attempts ({max_retries}) while fetching token. Exiting...")
                return None

            # phase 2: trends data
            for retry in range(max_retries):
                time.sleep(5)
                req_string = json.dumps(request['related_queries'], separators=(',', ':'))
                encoded_req = urllib.parse.quote(req_string, safe=':,+')
                url = f"https://trends.google.com/trends/api/widgetdata/relatedsearches?hl={hl}&tz=0&req={encoded_req}&token={tokens['related_queries']}&tz=0"
                response = s.get(url, impersonate=browser_versions[current_browser_version_index], cookies=cookies)
                print(f"URL: {url}")
                if response.status_code == 200:
                    content = response.text[5:]
                    try:
                        file_name = f"trends_data_{os.getpid()}.json"
                        with open(file_name, 'w') as json_file:
                            json_file.write(content)
                        
                        # Remove first line from the file
                        with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
                            lines = f.readlines()[1:]
                        with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
                            f.writelines(lines)
                        
                        # Load JSON content from the file
                        with open(file_name, 'r') as json_file:
                            data = json.load(json_file)
                        
                        # Extract and print queries and values from both rankedLists separately
                        for item in data['default']['rankedList'][0]['rankedKeyword']:
                            print(f"Top: {item['query']}, Value: {item['value']}")
                        
                        for item in data['default']['rankedList'][1]['rankedKeyword']:
                            print(f"Rising: {item['query']}, Value: {item['value']}")
                        
                        return content
                    except json.JSONDecodeError:
                        print(f"Failed to decode JSON while fetching trends data, retrying {retry + 1}/{max_retries}")
                else:
                    print(f"Error {response.status_code} while fetching trends data, retrying {retry + 1}/{max_retries}")
            else:
                print(f"Exceeded maximum retry attempts ({max_retries}) while fetching trends data.")

        if not data_fetched and browser_retry < browser_switch_retries:
            time.sleep(5)
            current_browser_version_index = (current_browser_version_index + 1) % len(browser_versions)
            print(f"Switching browser version to {browser_versions[current_browser_version_index]} and retrying...")

    print(f"Exceeded maximum browser switch attempts ({browser_switch_retries}). Exiting...")
    return None

# Example
keywords = ["test"]
trends_data = fetch_trends_data(keywords)
print(trends_data)
```

Comment: Hello, please don't post code only and add an explantation as to why you think that this is the optimal solution. People are supposed to learn from your answer, which might not occur if they just copy paste code without knowing why it should be used.