# Python - Pytrends ResponseError Code 400 429

Tags: python, request, response, google-trends

I keep getting an error with Pytends that prevents me from grabbing data for a keyword from Google Trends.

I've seen a similar question, but the code error was 429.
[Pytrends: The request failed: Google returned a response with code 429](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50571317/pytrends-the-request-failed-google-returned-a-response-with-code-429)

My code:

```
import pytrends
from pytrends.request import TrendReq
password = "***********" ; email = "********@gmail.com"
pytrend = TrendReq(email, password)

# WORKS FINE ABOVE, ERROR OCCURS WITH THIS LINE OF CODE BELOW
pytrends.build_payload(kw_list=["Python", "Java"], geo="US")
```

ERROR:

```
 ResponseError: The request failed: Google returned a response with code 400.
```

I've worked with pytrend before over a year ago, and it worked fine. So I'm a bit baffled. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm using the latest version of Pytrends, 4.4.0

Answer (score 0):

You defined pytrend (without an s) and are trying to use pytrends (with an s)