# The request failed: Google returned a response with code 429 in pytrends library

Tags: python

I am trying to fetch Google trends data from the pytrends library and since the last two weeks, I keep getting this same error : The request failed: Google returned a response with code 429. I went through the stackoverflow discussions for this same error, but the solutions suggested like update the pytrends library didn't work. I also tried giving proxies but that also didn't work. Has Google recently changed it's rate limit policy? Or is there any other way to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I proposed a different solution that now seems to work.
Please checkout again the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50571317/pytrends-the-request-failed-google-returned-a-response-with-code-429).