# pytrends.request.TrendReq._get_data() got multiple values help wanted (Python)

Tags: python, google-trends

I'm working on a script that looks at Google Trends and have hit a bit of a problem in regards to a variable called "params":

This is the code I have:

```
param = {
'hl': 'en-US',
}

response = requests.get(**INSERT URL HERE**, params=param)

class TrendReq(UTrendReq):
    def _get_data(self, url, method=GET_METHOD, trim_chars=0, **kwargs):
        return super()._get_data(url, method=GET_METHOD, trim_chars=trim_chars, params=param, **kwargs)

pt = TrendReq()
```

I'm getting the response:

```
TypeError: pytrends.request.TrendReq._get_data() got multiple values for keyword argument 'params'
```

I'm not 100% sure I'm using this whole bit of script correctly, but if there are any thoughts around the multiple values, I would appreciate any ideas. I've been attempting to follow the [instructions on this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50571317/pytrends-the-request-failed-google-returned-a-response-with-code-429).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error description:

> "TypeError: got multiple values for argument" occurs when we overwrite the value of a positional argument with a keyword argument in a function call.

Which means you have inadvertently created a positional argument called `params` in the `_get_data()` method, which itself gets called multiple times in the `pytrends` package from function calls that set `params` already:

- [`.interest_over_time()`](https://github.com/GeneralMills/pytrends/blob/master/pytrends/request.py#L215)
- [`.interest_by_region()`](https://github.com/GeneralMills/pytrends/blob/master/pytrends/request.py#L268)
- [`.related_topics()`](https://github.com/GeneralMills/pytrends/blob/master/pytrends/request.py#L321)
- [`.related_queries()`](https://github.com/GeneralMills/pytrends/blob/master/pytrends/request.py#L373)
- [`.today_searches()`](https://github.com/GeneralMills/pytrends/blob/master/pytrends/request.py#L436)
- [`.realtime_trending_searches()`](https://github.com/GeneralMills/pytrends/blob/master/pytrends/request.py#L453)
- [`.top_charts()`](https://github.com/GeneralMills/pytrends/blob/master/pytrends/request.py#L491)
- [`.suggestions()`](https://github.com/GeneralMills/pytrends/blob/master/pytrends/request.py#L517)
- [`.categories()`](https://github.com/GeneralMills/pytrends/blob/master/pytrends/request.py#L532)
- [`.get_historical_interest()`](https://github.com/GeneralMills/pytrends/blob/master/pytrends/request.py#L545)

...thus resulting in the conflict of two different `params` set.

Solution:

If all you need to set is `accept-language` header and the corresponding `geo=` URL parameter then simply define it when you instance the `TrendReq` parser:

```py
pytrends = TrendReq(hl='en-US', ...)
```

Or don't set it at all, since `hl='en-US'` is set by default.